# famo.us handler.js errors after altering main.js

Tags: famo.us

After installing famo.us, anytime I try to modify the main.js file with anything other than the default surfaceImage grunt serve simply throws a bunch of handler.js errors and will not load the page.

I can add different images and modify the size of the imageSurface without any issues but as soon as I try to add a surface or add properties to the existing imageSurface I get errors.

This happens with all of the examples posted on GitHub as well (running from the example main.js file).  The errors below are pretty typical of what I see anytime I modify the main.js file:

```
   >> File "app\src\main.js" changed.
Running "jscs:src" (jscs) task
Multiple var declaration at app/src/handler.js :
     6 |var mainContext = Engine.createContext();
     7 |
     8 |var surfaceA, surfaceB;
--------^
     9 |createSurfaces();
    10 |
Illegal trailing whitespace at app/src/handler.js :
    33 |    }
    34 |  });
    35 |
----------^
    36 |  surfaceB = new Surface({
    37 |    size: [100, 100],
Illegal trailing whitespace at app/src/handler.js :
    43 |    }
    44 |  });
    45 |
----------^
    46 |  var modifierB = new StateModifier({
    47 |    origin: [1, 1]
Illegal trailing whitespace at app/src/handler.js :
    47 |    origin: [1, 1]
    48 |  });
    49 |
----------^
    50 |  mainContext.add(surfaceA);
    51 |  mainContext.add(modifierB).add(surfaceB);
Missing line feed at file end at app/src/handler.js :
    50 |  mainContext.add(surfaceA);
    51 |  mainContext.add(modifierB).add(surfaceB);
    52 |}
--------^
>> 5 code style errors found!
Warning: Task "jscs:src" failed. Use --force to continue
```

.

I'm still super new to this, so I'm sure I'm missing something pretty stupid, not sure what though.  Anyone else have an issue like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are encountering are the style guides that Famo.us would like you to follow if you are interested in participating in the open source development, or building community plugins.

As you can see, the style guides are very picky.. If you want to just get up and running quick you can simply disable the packages that are enforcing the style. These are eslint and jscs..

Go into your Gruntfile.js and comment out the set of lines under "THIS LINE" or "THESE LINES" to make it look like the following..

Hope this works for you!

```
/*global module:false*/

/*Generated initially from grunt-init, heavily inspired by yo webapp*/

module.exports = function(grunt) {
    'use strict';

    // Load grunt tasks automatically
    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

    // Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
    require('time-grunt')(grunt);

    // Project configuration.
    grunt.initConfig({
        // Project settings
        config: {
            // Configurable paths
            app: 'app',
            dist: 'dist'
        },
        // THESE LINES ///////////////
        // eslint: {
        //     options: {
        //         config: '.eslintrc'
        //     },
        //     target: ['<%= config.app %>/src/**/**.js']
        // },
        // THESE LINES ///////////////
        // jscs: {
        //     src: ['<%= config.app %>/src/**/**.js', 'Gruntfile.js'],
        //     options: {
        //         config: '.jscsrc'
        //     }
        // },
        // Watches files for changes and runs tasks based on the changed files
        watch: {
            bower: {
                files: ['bower.json'],
                tasks: ['bower']
            },
            js: {
                files: ['<%= config.app %>/src/**/**.js'],
                // THIS LINE ///////////////
                // tasks: ['jscs', 'eslint'],
                options: {
                    livereload: true
                }
            },
            gruntfile: {
                files: ['Gruntfile.js']
            },
            css: {
                files: ['<%= config.app %>/css/{,*/}*.css'],
                options: {
                    livereload: true
                }
            },
            livereload: {
                options: {
                    livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
                },
                files: [
                    '<%= config.app %>/{,*/}*.html',
                    '<%= config.app %>/styles/**/**.css',
                    '<%= config.app %>/images/{,*/}*'
                ]
            }
        },
        // The actual grunt server settings
        connect: {
            options: {
                port: grunt.option('port') || 5555,
                livereload: 35729,
                // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside
                hostname: '0.0.0.0'
            },
            livereload: {
                options: {
                    open: true,
                    base: [
                        '.tmp',
                        '<%= config.app %>'
                    ]
                }
            },
            dist: {
                options: {
                    open: true,
                    base: '<%= config.dist %>',
                    livereload: false
                }
            }
        },

        // Empties folders to start fresh
        clean: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    dot: true,
                    src: [
                        '.tmp',
                        '<%= config.dist %>/*',
                        '!<%= config.dist %>/.git*'
                    ]
                }]
            },
            server: '.tmp'
        },

        // Automagically wire-up installed Bower components into your RequireJS config
        bower: {
            raget: {
                rjsConfig: '<%= config.app %>/src/requireConfig.js'
            }
        },

        rev: {
            dist: {
                files: {
                    src: [
                        '<%= config.dist %>/src/{,*/}*.js',
                        '<%= config.dist %>/css/{,*/}*.css',
                        // '<%= config.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.*',
                        '<%= config.dist %>/css/fonts/{,*/}*.*',
                        '<%= config.dist %>/*.{ico,png}'
                    ]
                }
            }
        },

        processhtml: {
            dev: {
                files: {
                    '.tmp/index.html': ['<%= config.app %>/index.html']
                }
            },
            dist: {
                files: {
                    '<%= config.dist %>/index.html': ['<%= config.app %>/index.html']
                }
            },
            options: {
                commentMarker: 'process'
            }
        },

        // Reads HTML for usemin blocks to enable smart builds that automatically
        // concat, uglify and revision files. Creates configurations in memory so
        // additional tasks can operate on them

        useminPrepare: {
            options: {
                dest: '<%= config.dist %>'
            },
            html: '<%= config.dist %>/index.html'
        },

        // Performs reqrite based on rev and the useminPrepare configuration
        usemin: {
            options: {
                assetsDirs: ['<%= config.dist %>', '<%= config.dist %>/images']
            },
            html: ['<%= config.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
            css: ['<%= config.dist %>/css/{,*/}*.css']
        },

        htmlmin: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                    collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
                    collapseWhitespace: true,
                    removeAttributeQuotes: true,
                    removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
                    removeEmptyAttributes: true,
                    removeOptionalTags: true,
                    removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                    useShortDoctype: true
                },
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= config.dist %>',
                    src: '{,*/}*.html',
                    dest: '<%= config.dist %>'
                }]
            }
        },

        // Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
        copy: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    dot: true,
                    cwd: '<%= config.app %>',
                    dest: '<%= config.dist %>',
                    src: [
                        '**/**.{ico,png,txt,jpg}',
                        '.htaccess',
                        'images/{,*/}*.webp',
                        // '{,*/}*.html',
                        'styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*',
                        'lib/famous/**/**.css'
                    ]
                }]
            }
        },
        requirejs: {
            compile: {
                options: {
                    optimize: 'uglify2',
                    uglify2: {
                        mangler: {
                            toplevel: true
                        }
                    },
                    baseUrl: '<%= config.app %>/src',
                    mainConfigFile: '<%= config.app %>/src/requireConfig.js',
                    name: 'almond',
                    include: 'main',
                    insertRequire: ['main'],
                    out: '<%= config.dist %>/src/main.js',
                    wrap: true
                }
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.registerTask('serve', function(target) {
        if (target === 'dist') {
            return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
        }

        grunt.task.run([
            'clean:server',
            // THESE LINES ///////////////
            // 'jscs',
            // 'eslint',
            'processhtml:dev',
            'connect:livereload',
            'watch'
        ]);
    });

    grunt.registerTask('build', [
        'clean:dist',
        // THESE LINES ///////////////
        // 'jscs',
        // 'eslint',
        'processhtml:dist',
        'useminPrepare',
        'requirejs',
        'concat',
        'cssmin',
        'uglify',
        'copy:dist',
        'rev',
        'usemin',
        'htmlmin'
    ]);

    grunt.registerTask('default', [
        'build'
    ]);

};
```

Comment: I have `gruntfile.js` but it doesn't look like this.  It only has 22 lines.  Here it is even though SO will make it look ugly.
/*global module:false*/

/*Generated initially from grunt-init, heavily inspired by yo webapp*/

module.exports = function(grunt) {
  'use strict';

  // Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
  require('time-grunt')(grunt);

  // Load grunt config
  require('load-grunt-config')(grunt, {
    init: true,
    data: {
      config: {
        // Configurable paths
        app: 'app',
        dist: 'dist'
      }
    }
  });
};

Comment: @skb did you use the toolbelt to install?

Comment: @johntraver I'm using the toolbelt and wondering where to modify the jscs rules such as `disallowTrailingWhitespace`. Any help appreciated!

Comment: @wdm There is a `.jscsrc` file in the root directory of your project containing all the style rules.

Answer (score 0):

A short cut to force it to run or build would be to use the `--force` option. 
Like:

```
grunt serve --force
```

or

```
grunt --force
```

just make sure there are no non-formatting issues.